# Create generic struct that implements substructs

Tags: go

Im a bit newer to golang and struggle to make this work.
I create a generic structure with some subtypes in form of payloads.

```
type Item struct {
payload Payload
}

type Payload struct {
Name: String
}

type SubscriptionPayload struct {
subscriptionId string
payload
}

type ResourcePayload struct{
resourceId string 
payload
}
```

My goal would be that I can generate items where the payload contains both the common and specific attributes of the payload structs. So for example
item1 := {"payload": {"name": "subscription1", "subscriptionId": "1234}
item2 := {"payload": {"name": "resource1", "resourceId": "5678"}

I thought by passing the payload as an attribute in the subtype this would inherit the payload attributes, but then my problem is that I cant pass the subtype directly as a value for payload inside the item.

Comment: There are no "subtypes" in Go as Go has no inheritance. Most likely you simply cannot do what you try to do.

Answer (score 1):

i think y want something there, its classic

```golang
type Item struct {
    Payload Payload
}

type Payload struct {
    Name string
    *SubscriptionPayload
    *ResourcePayload
}

type SubscriptionPayload struct {
    SubscriptionId string
}

type ResourcePayload struct{
    ResourceId string
}
```

or y may asking of constraint struct, ex: (not recomended, if y new in go)

```golang
type QuotaType interface {
    Quota | []any
}

type Quota struct {
    Limit      uint64

}

type GeneralQuota[T QuotaInterface] struct {
    Id         string
    Bytes      *T
    Keys       *T
}

func main() {
    var q Quota
    var gq GeneralQuota[Quota]
    gq.Keys = &q
}
```

and previosly coment about ifaces good and work too

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use interface instead! An interface type is defined as a set of method signatures. A value of interface type can hold any value that implements those methods.

```
type Item struct {
    Payload IPayload
}

type IPayload interface {
    GetName() string
}

type Payload struct {
    Name string
}

func (p *Payload) GetName() string { return p.Name }

type SubscriptionPayload struct {
    SubscriptionId string
    Payload
}

type ResourcePayload struct {
    ResourceId string
    Payload
}
```

[A Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/methods/9)

Answer (score 0):

One way you can handle this is by defining an interface for the common part (i.e., the `Payload` struct). This interface can be as simple as the following or you can include more functionality based on the common behavior.

```golang
type Payloader interface {
    GetPayloadName() string
}
```

All your structs that include `payload` struct will automatically get the interface implementation. Then, since each `Item.payload` implements this interface, you can perform a type assertion to get the concrete type. Below is a complete implementation for the example you provided.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var item Item

    item = Item{
        payload: &SubscriptionPayload{
            subscriptionId: "1234",
            Payload: Payload{
                Name: "subscription1",
            },
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(item.payload.GetPayloadName())
    if subsPayl, ok := item.payload.(*SubscriptionPayload); ok {
        fmt.Println(subsPayl.subscriptionId)
    }

    item = Item{
        payload: &ResourcePayload{
            resourceId: "5678",
            Payload: Payload{
                Name: "resource1",
            },
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(item.payload.GetPayloadName())
    if subsPayl, ok := item.payload.(*ResourcePayload); ok {
        fmt.Println(subsPayl.resourceId)
    }
}

type Item struct {
    payload Payloader
}

type Payload struct {
    Name string
}

func (p *Payload) GetPayloadName() string {
    return p.Name
}

type SubscriptionPayload struct {
    subscriptionId string
    Payload
}

type ResourcePayload struct {
    resourceId string
    Payload
}

type Payloader interface {
    GetPayloadName() string
}
```

Since the type is defined based on the `Payload.Name` and we can get this value using the `Payloader` interface, you can define a `switch` code block to perform proper actions based on the `Payload.Name`.